# overScrollBy doesn't always bounce back in Lollipop (5.x) platform

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have overridden `overScrollBy` method in `ScrollView` based on the following post:

http://jasonfry.co.uk/blog/android-overscroll-revisited/

It is working fine on other platform version, but Lollipop is unable to bounce back if fling motion is applied to the `ScrollView`.

Anyone encountered this issue and found a workaround?

Called in constructor`setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);`

Here relevant code which I have overridden in my custom `ScrollView`class:

```
@Override
protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX,
                               int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY,
                               int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent) {
    return super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, scrollX, scrollY,
            scrollRangeX, scrollRangeY, maxOverScrollX, OVER_SCROLL_AMOUNT,
            isTouchEvent);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you post your current code?

Comment: It seems to be working as intended for me, can you please expand on exactly what's going wrong, and post some code as well?

Comment: Updated the relevant code, you scroll over bounds normally and then apply fling motion and the scrollview just stops.

Comment: I have posted a solution to prevent the scroll from getting stuck.  Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I digged into changes between KitKat an Lollipop `ScrollView`. Following code solves my issue.

```
@TargetApi(21)
@Override
public boolean dispatchNestedFling(float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
    // Not consumed means it wasn't handled because ScrollView
    // doesn't take over scrolling bounds into scroll range,
    // so we fling it ourselves to get it bounce back
    if (getOverScrollMode() == OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS && !consumed) {
        fling((int) velocityY);

        return true;
    } else {
        return super.dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on Lollipop 5.1 . So I overrode that function with only these 2 lines: `fling((int) velocity); return true;` . And now it works.